# Is this the correct hypothesis of softmax regression?

Tags: regression, logistic, nonlinear-regression, softmax

Consider a dataset of $m$ training examples, $n$ features and $K$ classes.
So we have a feature matrix $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{M}_{m, n}(\mathbb{R})$ and a weight matrix $\boldsymbol{\Theta} \in \mathbb{M}_{n, K}(\mathbb{R})$

Now, the softmax function as per Wikipedia is given as :
$$
s(\mathbf{\vec z})_{i} = \frac{\exp(z _{i})}{\sum_{j=1}^{|\mathbf{\vec z}|}\exp(z _{j})}
$$
Applying the exponential function element-wise, we can rewrite the above formula as :
$$
s(\mathbf{\vec z}) = \frac{\exp(\mathbf{\vec z})}{\|\exp(\mathbf{\vec z})\|}_{1}
$$
Conforming to the above formulation, the hypothesis of softmax regression is given as :
$$
\mathbf{h}_{\boldsymbol{\Theta}}(\mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)}) = \frac{\exp(\boldsymbol{\Theta} \cdot \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)})}{\|\exp(\boldsymbol{\Theta} \cdot \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)})\|}_{1}
$$
Where $\mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)}$ is the ith training example.

This hypothesis will output a K-dimensional vector but its only for a single training example.
Then it stands to reason that a "vectorized" hypothesis will output a $n \times K$ matrix :
$$
\mathbf{\vec h}_{\boldsymbol{\Theta}}(\mathbf{X}) = \left[\mathbf{h}_{\boldsymbol{\Theta}}(\mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)})_{k}\right]_{n \times K}
$$
Here :
$$
\mathbf{h}_{\boldsymbol{\Theta}}(\mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)})_{k} = \frac{\exp(\boldsymbol{\theta}_{k} \cdot \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)})}{\|\exp(\boldsymbol{\Theta} \cdot \mathbf{\vec x}^{(i)})\|}_{1}
$$
Where $\boldsymbol{\theta}_{k}$ is the kth column vector of $\boldsymbol{\Theta}$ .

I have never seen a proper closed formula for the hypothesis of softmax regression in any texts.
So, is my formulation correct?

Comment: A popular text that covers binary and multinomial logistic regression is *Elements of Statistical Learning.* It's available for free online. https://hastie.su.domains/Papers/ESLII.pdf

Comment: Have you looked at kernel regression?  Your kernel is softmax.  Also, look at radial basis function networks and kernel regression.

Comment: I am aware of kernel functions and the  kernel trick but I haven't seen something explicitly called kernel regression? Are you referring to GLMs by any chance?